# can't use cv::fileStorgae to save an XML file

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use `cv::fileStorage` to save the calibration result as an `XML` file like :

```
   cv::FileStorage fs = cv::FileStorage("calibration_result.xml",cv::FileStorage::FORMAT_XML||cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
```

this doesn't work but when I choose the `yml`extension  it works ?   any idea why is that happening ? 
thanks in advance !

Comment: How do you actually save the Mat/data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. It should work.

```
...
FileStorage fs("calibration_result.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
Mat R = Mat_<uchar >::eye  (3, 3),
    T = Mat_<double>::zeros(3, 1);

fs << "R" << R;                                      // Write cv::Mat
fs << "T" << T;
fs.release(); 
...
```

I've tested it and it writes file with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<R type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>u</dt>
  <data>
    1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1</data></R>
<T type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>d</dt>
  <data>
    0. 0. 0.</data></T>
</opencv_storage>
```

Comment: qthanks Andrey thanks for your answer it work but I still have a problem getting the reprojection error (big float number )into the file storage ! and by the way any idea how to get rid of <T type_id="opencv-matrix"> and similar texts ?

Comment: Can you show the code reproducing float writing problem? And I guess you can't get rid of <T type_id="opencv-matrix"> without changing opencv source code, as it's their format convention. If your data not very complex, you can write xml with standard file io methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653627/saving-a-double-variable-with-cvfilestorage