# saving a double variable with cv::fileStorage

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a calibration program that run  the camera calibration. I want to save the result of the calibration in a `YML` file which works without any problem except when I try to save the  **reprojection error** which is a double value here what I did:

```
cv::FileStorage fs= cv::FileStorage("calibration_result.yml",cv::FileStorage::WRITE); /*creating the storage file for the calibration results */

.......................................................


this->fs << "the camera matrix is "<<this->cameraMatrix;
.....................................................................
        this->fs<< "the number of used frames is "<<this->actualnumberOfFrames;
        ///this->fs<< " the reprojection error " << this->reprojectionError;   when I activate this line the storage stops at the **actualnumberOfFrames**
        this->fs<<"the used resolution is " << this->theFrameSIZE;
        this->fs << "used flags in the calirbation function" << this->flagsName;
        this->fs<<"the distortion Coefficients are "<< this->distortionCoeff;
        this->fs<<"the rotation vector is "<< this->rvec;
        this->fs <<"the tangiantiale vector" << this->tvecs;
......................................................
```

I double checked the variable value it's fine and  I really ned the value in the result file !

any Idea how I may solve this ? thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the whitespace at the start of your name?

From:

```
this->fs<< " the reprojection error " << this->reprojectionError;
```

To:

```
this->fs<< "the reprojection error " << this->reprojectionError;
```

Comment: I did!  but it didn't help ?

Comment: Was just a guess... rest of the code seems fine to me. `FileStorage` should accept `double` without a problem... are you really sure that all values are as expected? I don´t see an error in the code snippet you have give.